# Constant in an ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I get to this point:
$$\int \frac{1}{u^2+1}du=\int \frac{1}{x}dx $$
$$ \arctan(u)=\log(x)+C$$

What I would do now is the following:
$$\tan(\arctan(u))=\tan(\log(x)+C) $$
$$u=\tan(\log(x)+C)$$

However, in my book they change the constant C for K and rewrite the equation in the following way:
$$ u=\tan(\log(Kx))$$

Why would I randomly substitute $C$ with $\log(K)$? What is the reason behind doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: The logarithm function is onto. So there exists $K > 0$ such that $\log(K) = C$. Then, the author uses the product-to-sum rule of logarithms to rewrite as $\log(Kx)$.

Comment: May be the context gives you a clue? For example, you may want to have a solution valid for negative $x$, when $\log x$ would raise eyebrows, but you can handle those with a negative $K$. Similarly, if $x$ is something measured in meters (or feet), the multiplier $K$ can absorb those units easily.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts I just wanted to know the logic behind expressing the constant in that way but I am sure someone else will find useful the steps taken in order to express the result in that manner.